# How can I avoid Fatal signal 11 crash in Vuforia for Android?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am working on the FrameMarkers sample application with ~30 small markers, rendering simple 2D planes. My app has a few GUI buttons that when clicked, will change the displayed textures (between yellow or grey). This part works, but there is a problem where sometimes the app crashes and gives the following error:

```
11-22 12:52:36.361: A/libc(7197): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000010 (code=1), thread 7278 (Thread-527)
```

This is an example of how I switch grey textures to yellow:

```
// First, set the textures in the texture array
for (int i=0;i<30;i+2) {
    mTextures.set(i, textureYellow);
}

// Reinitialize the renderer
deinitApplicationNative();
initApplicationNative(mScreenWidth, mScreenHeight);
mGlView.queueEvent(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {                             
        mRenderer.initRendering();
    }
});
```

That is the suggested way to switch textures at run-time (see [here](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/rendering-opengl-es/set-mtextures-after-initial-call)), and I have it running inside `FrameMarkers.java` (it is triggered by a button click from another Activity through a Handler). I should reiterate that the app doesn't crash on every texture change. On each run it crashes at a different point, but I have isolated the problem to be somewhere in the process of changing textures and re-initializing the renderer (as it seems to happen after a button press).

- What could be causing this to crash so infrequently?
- Is there a safer way to change textures during run time in a Vuforia application?

Running this on Android 4.3.

Comment: I have clarified with some people over at Vuforia that this is indeed the correct way to change textures during run-time. You need to call the first two native methods on the main thread (`deinitApplicationNative()` and `initApplicationNative()`) and `mRender.initRendering()` on the GL thread. I removed the Handler and called the methods directly from the main thread and it crashes much less frequently.

Comment: Another interesting finding is that an older device running Android 2.3.3. doesn't suffer from this crash. Could it be that Android 4.3 deals with memory/garbage collection differently and causes a SIGSEGV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have solved this error. Indeed, the code in my original post is the correct way to switch textures during run-time (this has been confirmed by the admins on the Vuforia forums).

The problem was a threading issue. I had retrieved code for the `GUIManager` class from the Dominoes sample application to add buttons and other elements to the screen. That class uses a `Handler` to receive messages and then perform appropriate GUI-related tasks.

The problem is that you have to ensure `initApplicationNative()` is called on the Main thread, while `mRenderer.initRendering()` is called on the GLThread. Not only that, but if the array of textures is changing at any point between the `initApplicationNative()` call and the `mRenderer.initRendering()` calls, it can cause a failure in the native code (there are some `assert()` calls).

There is some more information about Threading in Vuforia here: https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/faq/android-which-methods-are-called-ui-vs-opengl-thread

I believe that there were timing issues, as well as sometimes functions were called on the wrong thread. To make my program work, I removed the Handlers from `FrameMarkers.java` and `GUIManager.java`, and called all of my texture-updating code from the Main thread.

This ensures that `deinitApplicationNative()` and `initApplicationNative()` are always called from the Main thread, whereas `mGlView.queueEvent()` ensures that the GL code runs on that thread.